# mkdirs() doesnt create new directory in android

Tags: java, android

I tried to make some folder in my storage and store image from camera into it, but mkdirs always return false, already tried using mkdir and canWrite, but still the same

```
2020-02-12 09:32:44.043 22914-23146/example.com.absensiapp D/TET: Folder Not Exist
2020-02-12 09:32:44.047 22914-23146/example.com.absensiapp D/TET: Failed To Create Directory
```

Here is the code for making the folder and save the image from camera

```
  String wholeFolderPath = fh.TRAINING_PATH + name;
  File dir = new File(wholeFolderPath);
  if(!dir.exists()) {
     Log.d("TET", "Folder Not Exist");
      //create new directory
      if(dir.mkdirs())
         fh.saveMatToImage(m, wholeFolderPath + "/");
      else
         Log.d("TET", "Failed To Create Directory");
   }
   else {
         Log.d("TET", "Folder Exist");
         //save the image to directory
         fh.saveMatToImage(m, wholeFolderPath + "/");
    }
```

Already put the permission in my manifest and main activity

Manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Main Activity :

```
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void checkPermission() {
    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `mkdir()` method, instead there is `canWrite()`

Comment: @SkypeDogg sorry, forgot to edit it. Tried using canWrite(), but still return false

Comment: `mkdirs()` creates whole path with all parent directories. If you want to create only this one directory, try `mkdir()`

Comment: Does the directory already exist?

Comment: Yes, don't forget `if (dir.exists()) return;
        dir.mkdir();`

Comment: @SkypeDogg already tried mkdir, still not works

Comment: @user207421 nope, I check that on my file manager and find none

Comment: Where you you call your directory creation? Try to do it inside `onRequestPermissionsResult()` after you have confirmed the permissions are granted.

Comment: @SkypeDogg sorry if its not clear enough, I will give the full method to call the mkdirs. I dont know how to call mkdirs in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` if its not inside `onCameraFrame` method

Comment: What interests me is where do you call `onCameraFrame()`

Comment: @SkypeDogg in other activity, not inside main activity

Comment: You should only call mkdir or mkdirs if the folder does not exist yet. If the folder already exists mkdir and mkdirs will return false. Further you are checking the return value at one occasion only.

Comment: And on Android Q you can not create a folder in that path.

Comment: Does your `TEST_PATH` and `TRAINING_PATH` end with `"/"`? Probably yes, but I need to ask.

Comment: @blackapps the folder doesnt exist yet, already check it.

Comment: @SkypeDogg yes, `String TRAINING_PATH = FOLDER_PATH + "/training/"`

Comment: `the folder doesnt exist yet, already check it. `. Its good you checked it yourself. But your code should do that to begin with. So please adapt your code.

Comment: @blackapps thx for it, tried to check it (edit the code, if its wrong please tell me) and it says already exist. But dont know how to resolve it. Any advice for it?

Comment: `if(dir.exists()) ` That should be `if(!dir.exists()) `

Comment: `if(!dir.exists()) if (!dir.mkdirs()){Toast(..could not create directory..); return;}`.

Comment: @blackapps thx, already edit the code, please take a look at it

Comment: Actually it should be `if (!dir.isDirectory())`, to catch the case where it is a file, not a directory, which should fail, not appear to succeed here and mysteriously fail later on. @blackapps

Comment: Your code is unreadable. You should return if the directory is not created. After that you would have one save call. Not two as you have now.

Comment: You do not have to check if it is a directory if your code is logic as it can never happen then that it is a file.

Comment: `fh.TRAINING_PATH + name;`. Nobody knows the full path you use. It will have been a path not accessable in Android Q. Thats all. Using another path would not have been a capitulation.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem. Downgrade my targetSdkVersion in build.gradle from 29 to 21

Comment: That is not a solution. Thats a capitulation.